# Is there any way to quickly expose C/C++ functions as MATLAB MEX files?

Tags: matlab, mex

I want to automate the generation of C source MEX files to expose C functions to MATLAB.  I'm hoping to find something similar to Boost.Python which uses C++ template meta-programming to wrap existing C++ code without having to modify the underlying source.  Note that I'm primarily interested in exposing functions right now, not class instances.  If there isn't any library out there that does this already is there a better approach to solve this problem than template meta-programming?  I've tried MATLAB's loadlibrary function but think its usage isn't intuitive for most end-users that I work with.

Currently I've been writing C source MEX wrappers manually which is very time consuming and, most importantly, its difficult to maintain the wrappers.  I don't have any issue with getting my MEX wrappers to work, it's just that the time required to expose the function to MATLAB via MEX is orders of magnitude more than what it takes me to expose them to Python.

This example shows the idea of what I'd like to do.  I'd like to expose the TimesTwo function to MATLAB which currently requires that I write a mexFunction that checks the input/output argument counts, converts MATLAB array pointers to C data types, calls the C function TimesTwo, then assigns the results to the MATLAB output arguments.
    #include "mex.h"
    #include "some_template_library.hpp"

```
// This is the function I want to expose
double TimesTwo(double in)
{
    return 2*in;
}

// This macro would expand to generate the mexFunction gateway
// It would also define the data types and perform error checking
// I realize the actual implementation would need to be more complex than this
EXPOSEFUNCTION(TimesTwo,double in, double out)
```

Comment: You can look here at how I generated a MEX-interface for a C++ library. There are several private MEX-files like [this one](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/dipimage/private/dip_segmentation.cpp), with trivial M-files providing documentation and calling the MEX-file. There is a large [header file](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/include/dip_matlab_interface.h) that knows how to get all C++ types from an `mxArray`, and back. Yes, this is still a bit of manual work for each function, but a lot less than writing each function interface from scratch.

Comment: The problem with fully automatic conversion is that MATLAB doesn’t allow changing the input arguments, and there is no way to find out from the function signature which arguments are inputs, outputs or both input/output. You can generally not do a 1-to-1 mapping of arguments from C++ to MATLAB.

Comment: For the first version of that library (back in 1999) I wrote a simplistic C parser that read all function signatures from the header files, and then automatically generated MEX-file code for them. That included a lot of knowledge about the library, and the assumption that the output argument in the RHS argument list was called `out`. It still required manual tweaking for some of the functions. After porting the library to C++ this was no longer workable IMO.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, That’s a good example of one approach and I agree that the C++ signature alone isn’t sufficient to identify i/o arguments.  So whatever I come up with will need some input from the programmer about expected MATLAB data types and input output status.